# Checking if input String date is in the future in java using parse, using "throws ParseException" when calling a method

Tags: java

I am working on a credit card validation portion of a Class but I am stuck at how to approach checking if the card has expired or not.

Payment Class(portion):

```
public Payment(...,String date,...)
{
    ...
    sendEmail(order,this.billingAddress,remark);
}

public boolean checkExpiry(String inDate) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date expiry=format.parse(inDate);
    Date today = new Date();
    if(today.before(expiry))
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isValid(String cardType,String cardNum,String date) throws ParseException
{
    if(cardType.equals("MasterCard") || cardType.equals("Visa")){
        if(cardNum.length()==16){
           if(checkExpiry(date)){
                return true;
            }else{
                remark="Credit Card Expired";
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            remark="Invalid Credit Card Number";
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        remark="Invalid Credit Card Type";
        return false;
    }
}

public void sendEmail(Order order, Address address, String remark)throws ParseException
{
    Email email = new Email(customer);
    if(this.isValid(cardType,cardNum,date)==true){
        email.success(order,address);
    }else{
        email.failure(this.getRemark());
    }
}
```

This is the method I am currently using. However, when making the method call in the constructor for the sendEmail() method, an error message tells me "unreported exception java.text.ParseException;must be caught or declared to be thrown".

I have 2 questions:

1)What should I do to make the class compile

2)Is there a simpler/more efficient way to check if the input string containing date is in the future?

Comment: What do you want an invalid date value to do?

Comment: return false to the isValid method which will set remark to "Credit Card Expired" and return false to the sendEmail method

Comment: `sendEmail` `throws ParseException` - it's clearly defined to do so.  Any method/constructor calling it either needs to handle the exception or re-throw it

Comment: Why is information only validated by the `sendEmail` method? Shouldn't the constructor validate input and fail immediately, never calling `sendEmail`?

Comment: An email is sent in case of failure informing customer WHY the transaction failed (invalid date, credit cardnumber, or credit card type)

Comment: You **should really** take a look at the Java Time API. This API replaces the `Date` and `Calendar` classes, which are considered obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)What should I do to make the class compile

`sendEmail` is defined to throw a possible `ParseException`

```
public void sendEmail(Order order, Address address, String remark)throws ParseException {...
```

Any method/constructor calling it needs to either handle or re-throw the exception.

I would suggest changing your constructor so it also throws `ParseException`....

```
public Payment(...,String date,...) throws ParseException {...
```

This will allow the exception to be bubbled up to the original caller

The caller would then need to deal with, may by catching it...

```
try {
    Payment payment = new Payment(...);
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    System.err.println("Failed to process your payment due to an error");
    // exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

or some such

> 2)Is there a simpler/more efficient way to check if the input string containing date is in the future?

That's a broad question.  My first feeling is, DON'T ACCEPT STRING DATES (sorry, but this is a real bug bear for me).

Your `Payment` class should only accept valid dates, it's not it's responsibility to convert the `String` to a date value (or make determinations about the format), that's someone else's responsibility.

Having said all that, I would recommend making use Java's newer (and improved) date/time functionality...

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("16/10/2018", pattern);
System.out.println(localDate);
```

Which prints `2018-10-16`.

You can then use something like `LocalDate.now().isAfter(localDate)` to then test if the date has expired or not (any any variation of `isBefore` and/or `equals` based on your needs)

Comment: I am studying Java in college, and this is a bonus part of an assignment. The brief shows the data being input as such--Payment payment1 = new Payment( order, "MasterCard","112233445566", "05/10/2018",add1,"Bank of X") ;--Which ,I believe, means that we should input the date as a String.I might be wrong though as this is only my second OOP program.Which is why I am really confused with the throws exception thing as we didnt really take that yet.

Comment: Your code has defined a contract to throw a `ParserException`, you either need to handle it or re-throw it